# Is there a performance benefit to awaiting lots of small Tasks over a large block of synchronous code?

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, asynchronous, task-parallel-library

I have a section of code that I need to run ~1000 instances of.  I'm using the Task Parallel Library to start 1k Tasks and then wait for them to finish with Await Task.WhenAll.  It is a fairly large collection of solely synchronous methods, involving many web requests and socket connections.

What effect, with regards to performance, would changing each operation (HttpWebRequest.GetResponse, Socket.Connect, etc) to an asynchronous method with an await (GetResponseAsync, ConnectAsync, etc) have?

I'm wondering if it might be able to share the CPU load better over multiple cores due to each method call being a Task, albeit with a larger memory overhead.  Is this correct or are my assumptions wrong here?

Comment: Try and measure... Also if you don't see CPU load significantly lower than 100% it is unlikely you get any benefits of rewriting (assuming your code is not sort of web server that needs to have way to easily start and wait for unbounded number of requests).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's hard to quantify, but if you're really jazzing the network IO, you really **need** to go async. Running sync IO, you'll starve the ThreadPool (which is where TPL runs the tasks) by having lots of parked threads waiting for their responses.

When the ThreadPool runs out of threads, there's quite a bit of latency before it decides to react to the pressure. It can really slow things down. You should notice a marked improvement in performance by switching to async IO.

As a general rule, the less time you spend hanging around in ThreadPool threads (blocking on IO) the better. Async keeps this time to an absolute minimum.

Comment: Sounds like I would definitely benefit by converting the major blockers (web requests, etc) to async methods.  Is there any downside, apart from making the code more complex? I had assumed a memory overhead?

Comment: @Mick I thought GetResponse is a synchronous method and BeginGetResponse/GetResponseAsync are asynchronous?  That article is a little over my head.  I'm not trying to change the way the request is done, so much as try to decide whether having the part getting the response run in a new Task would be beneficial, since then the TPL can decide how best to handle the CPU load.

Answer (score 2):

I'd be pretty cautious about making or accepting generalized statements about performance.  It's a tricky things, and usually involves a lot dependencies. Sometimes running 1000 things in parallel could be slower than running the same 1000 synchronously, other times it could be a lot quicker, it really depends on what those 1000 tasks are doing, the hardware those tasks are run on, memory etc etc etc.  There are a lot of variables in the equation.

Don't over engineer things anticipating benefits in performance, performance is something you frequently get surprised by, it's more important to be able to instrument and measure performance in a system and then make changes and measure that performance again.  A lot of the time the changes you have to make to get a system to perform can be surprising.